# MySQL multiple join, multiple sort maintain group

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display data from four tables.  Three of these tables constitute a one-to-many relationship.  I need to group certain data according to a shared suit_id and I need to be able to freely sort on fields from different tables.  I also need to be able to sort on more than one field from different tables.

- The data represents legal cases (suits) from court records.
- For each suit there are possibly many parties.
- There will only be one charge for any given party and that party_type will be "Defendant".

**DB structure:**

![Highlighted are the fields that I need to sort on.
The internal relation of suit_id to parent_suit_id may not be needed.  I added it for testing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1FJn.png)

The following is my current query which returns the correct data.  The data is properly grouped by suit_id but the sorting is off and my query doesn't allow me to control the sorting.

```
SELECT
s.suit_id,
s.case_number,
p.party_id,
p.name,
c.charge_id,
c.charge_code
FROM suit_party sp
    LEFT JOIN suit s
        ON sp.suit_id = s.suit_id
    LEFT JOIN (     
        SELECT pp.* FROM party pp
        WHERE pp.party_type != 'Bond Entity'
        ORDER BY pp.last_name DESC
    ) p
    ON sp.party_id = p.party_id
LEFT JOIN charge c
    ON p.party_id = c.party_id
WHERE p.party_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY sp.party_id, sp.suit_id
```

**Sample output**

```
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| suit_id | case_number | party_id | name             | charge_id | charge_code |
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
|       1 | 66519GE     |        1 | Trouble, Tony T. |         1 | 262061253   |
|       1 | 66519GE     |        2 | Law, Officer     |      NULL | NULL        |
|       2 | 2013A262076 |        3 | Bad, Bobby B.    |         2 | 0528        |
|       2 | 2013A262076 |        5 | Police, Peter    |      NULL | NULL        |
|       3 | A357654KK   |        6 | Krook, Kimberly  |         3 | 2143        |
|       3 | A357654KK   |        7 | Crime, Capn      |      NULL | NULL        |
|       4 | B357654KK   |        8 | Krook, Kimberly  |         4 | 0660        |
|       4 | B357654KK   |        9 | Law, Officer     |      NULL | NULL        |
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to be able to sort by name and charge_code while keeping the suit_id's properly grouped.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6daf9

Comment: Why not add GROUP BY sp.party_id, sp.suit_id, p.name, c.charge_code? Then it would sort by name and charge_code within the party_id and suit_id mapping.

Comment: Tried that just now and it didn't affect the sorting.  The order stayed the same.

Comment: Changing the ORDER BY clause in the sub-query doesn't affect the order, either.

Comment: Could you paste the result after you tried this?

Comment: I would like to be able to adjust the sorting at will.  Including sorting on fields not represented in the sample output (i.e. p.last_name, p.state, etc.).

Comment: it looks ordered already !!  if you add `order  by name,code`  whats happening?

Comment: If I add p.name, c.charge_code after the existing sp.party_id, sp.suit_id then nothing changes.  If I add p.name, c.charge_code _in place of_ the existing sp.party_id, sp.suit_id then the suit_id's no longer group properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `order by` is that you are including `sp.party_id`.  The pair uniquely defines each row, so no other sort criteria are necessary.

I think this will fix your problem:

```
order by sp.suit_id, p.name, c.charge_code
```

Comment: I think you're referring to my GROUP BY (I edited your post).  I tried what you suggested and it does group by the secondary and tertiary clause.  I'm looking to sort the output, say, alphabetically or numerically by given fields.  So, although, they are being grouped properly, the output is not sequential. Thank you for your point regarding sp.party_id being unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect most of your problem is that you have not normalised the data.  You have multiple partyids for what appear to be the same person.  (Law Officer and Kimberly Crook are two) You need to have only one entry for each of them in your party table then using the partyid as FK elsewhere makes more sense.  You have essentially told your application that the instances of LO and KC are different people with the same name.  Why, then should it put them together?

You should rewrite your test data first:

```
    INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `name`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `suffix`, `original_address`, `address`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `zip4`, `race`, `gender`, `dob`, `party_type`, `party_status`, `last_updated`, `avs_status`, `avs_message`) VALUES
(1, 'Trouble, Tony T.', 'Tony', 'T.', 'Trouble', '', '4338 My Street River TX 12345', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'White', 'M', '09/29/1987', 'Defendant', NULL, '06/16/2013', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Law, Officer', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '123 Police Street', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Officer', NULL, '06/12/2013', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Bad, Bobby B.', 'Bobby', 'B.', 'Bad', '', '3463 Some Rd. Bend, MS 32432', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'White', 'M', '04/19/1960', 'Defendant', NULL, '06/19/2013', NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Bond, Barbara', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '546 Bond Street', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Bond Entity', NULL, '06/07/2013', NULL, NULL),
(5, 'Police, Peter', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '123 Police Street', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Officer', NULL, '06/06/2013', NULL, NULL),
(6, 'Krook, Kimberly', 'Kimberly', '', 'Krook', '', '23423 Kims Place Kimtown, KS 32343', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'White', 'M', '07/11/1993', 'Defendant', NULL, '06/14/2013', NULL, NULL),
(7, 'Crime, Capn', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '123 Police Street', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Officer', NULL, '06/14/2013', NULL, NULL),

INSERT INTO `suit_party` (`suit_party_id`, `suit_id`, `party_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(5, 2, 5),
(6, 3, 6),
(7, 3, 7),
(8, 4, 6),
(9, 4, 2);
```

as in this fiddle.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e771b/3

For speed, I have removed the FK constraints and I accept there is work to do on this but ultimately I hope it demonstrates what you need.  By fiddling with the order by, you can get what I think you are asking now...

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up in the sample data of the transaction which I had posted originally.  I have now replaced the transaction with this: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78192/1).  So, yes, Kimberly Krook and Officer Law are the same person, however, they are entered in more than once because they are both party to two separate suits.  I corrected the sample data now to reflect the proper case numbers.